# append only if item isn't already appended?

Tags: python

In my Python application, I have the following lines:

```
for index, codec in enumerate(codecs):
    for audio in filter(lambda x: x['hls']['codec_name'] == codec, job['audio']):
        audio['hls']['group_id'].append(index)
```

How can I only trigger the `append` statement if the index hasn't been already appended previously?

Comment: post the data of codecs

Comment: I'd suggest you use a set , if order doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply test `if` your index `not in` your list:

```
for index, codec in enumerate(codecs):
    for audio in filter(lambda x: x['hls']['codec_name'] == codec, job['audio']):
        if index not in audio['hls']['group_id']:
            audio['hls']['group_id'].append(index)
```

Comment: And now it's O(n^3). Not a problem for small numbers, but still poor design

Answer (score 4):

I think you're going about this backwards, very inefficiently. Right now, for each name, you loop through the entire `job['audio']` sequence to find a match. This is O(n^2).

Instead, you could do a single pass over `coedecs` to record the first occurrence of each one:

```
codec_map = {codec: len(codecs) - i - 1 for i, codec in enumerate(reversed(codecs))}
```

Reversing allows you to select the first index instead of the last, since the dictionary will contain the last key encountered. If you don't care whether it's first or last, you can simplify:

```
codec_map = {codec: i for i, codec in enumerate(codecs)}
```

Now the inner loop only needs to run once:

```
for audio in job['audio']:
    if audio['hls']['codec_name'] in codec_map:
        audio['hls']['group_id'].append(codec_map[audio['hls']['codec_name']])
```

This solution is O(N), and allows you to check things more efficiently.

Comment: This is the efficient way to do it - and should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
for index, codec in enumerate(codecs):
    for audio in filter(lambda x: x['hls']['codec_name'] == codec, job['audio']):
        if index in audio['hls']['group_id']:
            pass
        else:
           audio['hls']['group_id'].append(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `in` operator in `list` works, but it is less efficient than `in` operator in `set`. You can use the set data structure to improve the efficiency:

```py
visited_indices = set()
for index, codec in enumerate(codecs):
    for audio in filter(lambda x: x['hls']['codec_name'] == codec, job['audio']):
        if index not in visited_indices:
            audio['hls']['group_id'].append(index)
            visited_indices.add(index)
```